# Issues with Python sqlite3 and query optimization

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am using sqlite3 and Python 3.8 to build a manipulate a financial tick database which has a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "daily_price" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "date"  DATETIME NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    "Open"  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "High"  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Low"   REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Close" REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Volume"    INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    "Adj_Open"  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Adj_High"  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Adj_Low"   REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Adj_Close" REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Adj_Volume"    INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    "Dividend"  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Split" REAL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Symbol"    TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

This table is roughly 30 million rows long. And on that table there are 4 indexes which are meant to improve query performance for what I foresaw to be typical queries.

```
CREATE INDEX "dividend_idx" ON "daily_price" (
    "date"  ASC,
    "Symbol"    ASC,
    "Dividend"
) WHERE "Dividend" > 0;

CREATE INDEX "socv_idx" ON "daily_price" (
    "date"  ASC,
    "Symbol"    ASC,
    "Open",
    "Close",
    "Volume"
);

CREATE INDEX "split_idx" ON "daily_price" (
    "date"  ASC,
    "Symbol"    ASC,
    "Split"
) WHERE "Split" <> 1;

CREATE INDEX "symbol_idx" ON "daily_price" (
    "Symbol"    ASC,
    "date"  ASC
);
```

I arrived at the form above after iteratively building different index strategies, testing queries representing basic use cases, observing performance, then as needed digging deeper with EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN.

Building the indexes only takes a few minutes and I intend to completely blow them away before updating the table en'bulk, then rebuilding them. They do however nearly double the size on disk (+83%) and this is just a test database before I move on to a larger 100+ GB one **so if this can be done a better way I would be happy to hear suggestions.**

With background out of the way, my issue is with some queries where the optimizer will choose a less than optimal index causing search time to explode. For instance if I take this query:

```
SELECT Symbol 
FROM daily_price 
WHERE Open > 5 AND Volume > 1000000 
AND Dividend > 0 AND Dividend > 1 
and Dividend/Open>.05;
```

The EXPLAIN is:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX dividend_idx.

And it only takes about 200 mS, but if I attempt to use DISTINCT, GROUP BY, or an outer SELECT FROM it takes minutes...

Using DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Symbol 
FROM daily_price 
WHERE Open > 5 AND Volume > 1000000 
AND Dividend > 0 AND Dividend > 1 
and Dividend/Open>.05;
```

Causes the EXPLAIN to become:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX symbol_idx

Using instead now GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Symbol 
FROM daily_price 
WHERE Open > 5 AND Volume > 1000000 
AND Dividend > 0 AND Dividend > 1 
and Dividend/Open>.05
GROUP BY Symbol;
```

also causes the EXPLAIN to become:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX symbol_idx

Whereas using a sub query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Symbol 
FROM( SELECT FROM daily_price 
WHERE Open > 5 AND Volume > 1000000 
AND Dividend > 0 AND Dividend > 1 
and Dividend/Open>.05);
```

causes the EXPLAIN to again be:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX symbol_idx

**What is causing the optimizer to think it makes sense to use the symbol_idx index during lookup when requesting a DISTINCT symbol or performing GROUP BY when before it understood that the dividend_idx index was the quickest way to get the shortlist?**

I appreciate I could just pipe it into a pandas DataFrame or otherwise find the unique values but I would prefer to do this correctly the SQL way.

Below are some example Queries which work as expected and appear to have sane query plans. Originally I included these above but they were distracting; however I thought they could be of some value so have left them:

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price WHERE Symbol = "AAPL";
```

Takes roughly 15-30 mS and returns 10k rows. Explain detail:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING INDEX symbol_idx (Symbol=?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Symbol FROM daily_price WHERE Symbol Like 'AA%';
```

Takes roughly 30-40 mS and returns 27 rows. Explain:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING COVERING INDEX symbol_idx (Symbol>? AND
> Symbol<?)

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price 
WHERE date BETWEEN "1999-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" AND "2000-11-18 00:00:00+00:00";
```

Takes roughly 175-225 mS and returns ~690k rows. Explain:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING INDEX socv_idx (date>? AND date<?)

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price 
WHERE date LIKE "1999-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" 
AND Open BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND Volume > 1000000;
```

Takes roughly 10-15 mS and returns 12 rows. Explain:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING INDEX socv_idx (date>? AND date<?)

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price WHERE Dividend > 0;
```

Takes roughly 65-75 mS and returns ~300k rows. Explain:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX dividend_idx

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price WHERE Split <> 1;
```

Takes roughly 15-25 mS and returns ~6k rows. Explain:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX split_idx

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price 
WHERE date BETWEEN "1999-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" AND "2000-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" 
AND Dividend > 0;
```

Takes roughly 15-25 mS and returns ~6k rows. Explain:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING INDEX dividend_idx (date>? AND date<?)

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price 
WHERE Symbol = "AAPL" and Dividend > 0;
```

Takes roughly 10-20 mS and returns 66 rows. Explain:

> SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING INDEX symbol_idx (Symbol=?)

```
SELECT * FROM daily_price 
WHERE Open > 50 AND Volume > 1000000 
AND Dividend > 0 AND Dividend > 1 
AND Dividend/Open>.05;
```

Takes roughly 150-200 mS and returns 75 rows. Explain:

> SCAN TABLE daily_price USING INDEX dividend_idx

```
SELECT 
    Symbol 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Symbol,Avg(Volume)'avg_vol' 
    FROM 
        daily_price WHERE date BETWEEN "1999-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" AND "2000-11-18 00:00:00+00:00" 
    GROUP BY Symbol)
WHERE avg_vol > 1000000;
```

Takes roughly 3000 mS and returns 300 rows. Explain:

> ```
> id  parent    notused   detail 
>  2    0       0         CO-ROUTINE 1
>  8    2       0         SEARCH TABLE daily_price USING COVERING INDEX socv_idx (date>? AND date<?)
> 15    2       0         USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
> 52    0       0         SCAN SUBQUERY 1
> ```

Comment: You could try to create a view for the query that works with the correct index and then use `SELECT DISTINCT Symbol FROM viewname`. Just an idea, I don't know if it will work.

Comment: Unsurprisingly if I delete the index on symbol 'symbol_idx' then the problem query works great and only takes 170 mS using the dividend index 'dividend_idx'. But, that breaks a number of the other queries where a lookup by symbol is requested. I would have thought it would fall back on literally any of the other indexes as they all have date and Symbol and so should be covering but instead it walks through the whole table... I have read that specifying an index as part of a query is generally frowned upon as the optimizer is supposed to know better, wouldnt a view in effect be doing this?

Comment: Further, attempting to use INDEXED BY and then specifying directly an index fails as the query plan states there is no solution. I think I am misunderstanding something fundamental to the way lockups are performed using an index...